# Different @ModelAttribute in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelattribute

What  the difference between

```
Myfunction(@ ModelAttribute("user") User user)
```

And

```
Myfunction(@ModelAttribute User user)
```

Answer (score 3):

The outcome is the same, but the difference is between explicit and [implicit (default) naming](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html)

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type), based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class "mypackage.OrderAddress"

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I feel difference in only one place.

`Myfunction(@ModelAttribute User user)` didn't work for me in Linux OS.

Instead I have to replace it with `Myfunction(@ ModelAttribute("user") User user)` to make it work.